# Why does adding float-left to buttons in a row cause the spacing between them to change?

Tags: html, css

I have three buttons like this:

```
<div class="float-left">
   <button class="small">X</button>
   <button class="small">Y</button>
   <button class="small">Z</button>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS that's applied to these:

```
button.small {
   font-size: 1.4rem;
   margin: 0 0.2rem;
   padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
   float: left;
}
```

When I apply the float: left to these I notice the spacing
in between the buttons changes. Can someone tell me why 
this is? Does it make a difference with margins or something like that?

Comment: You are setting margins, so what should you expect? if you want to get rid of the space, use negative margins http://jsfiddle.net/qG5yy/ (dirty way though)

Comment: It won't: http://jsfiddle.net/YamwM/

Comment: @abhitalks: Your markup is not the same as the one in the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, no whitespaces. I see now, that you have answered that in detail though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating the buttons turns them into block-level elements. Because of this, the whitespace between the buttons in the markup has no effect. Without floating them, they would normally be laid inline, causing the whitespace between them to push them apart just as spaces separate words in a sentence. Note that in HTML, [contiguous whitespace sequences behave as if they were a single regular space character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1).

The only spacing that remains in effect are the `0.2rem` margins that you've set (which incidentally [don't collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)). These margins are the same regardless of whether the buttons are inline-level or block-level.